# How do I fix there is no such module error in python 2.6?

Tags: python, macos

I've been using python 2.7 and after installation of python 2.7. All of the scripts have run successfully, but suddenly today, when I run python, it is recognized with python 2.6, so for one of the python packages I get the following error:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: 
No module named htseq-count
```

i am not sure why it happens. The path environment variable for python is set to:

```
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/bin:${PATH}" export PATH
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Can you post your exact error message?

Comment: Also, please format your question better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your code relies on a particular version of Python, you should specify `python2.7` or `python2.6` instead of just `python`.

If this "suddenly" happened it's possible that installing some other software modified your `$PATH` so that the old version of Python now has priority (it's possible for multiple versions to be on your `$PATH`; it uses the first one it finds).

If you move these two lines to the bottom of the file they're in (maybe `~/.profile`) it may correct this.

```
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

You can type `which python` in Terminal you can see what binary it finds when looking for `python` on your `$PATH`.

If you don't mind using Python 2.6, you can probably install the missing package by typing this in your terminal:

```
easy_install-2.6 htseq
```

Comment: @nana Try moving the lines defining the `$PATH` to the bottom of the file they're in. "how has it been changed suddenly??" It cannot change by itself, something you did caused it to change. As I said in my post, some software installations can cause this.

Comment: @nana Good to hear. If this answer solved your problem, it would be nice if you could click the checkmark to the left of this post (below the voting arrows) to "accept" it.

Comment: yes recently i downloaded other tools. as you mentioned, so it seems it has changed python path accordingly. if i type "which python" it gives /usr/bin/python i added it on path in bash profile, and then it works again with 2.7 now. many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are applying  different python version to be used.

type

```
which python
```

under your control.

see which python you are using, you should config the one using python 2.7

```
python --version
```